# jquery div movement using css with panel changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

quite a large question here. Basically im making a site that has a central heading when you load the index.html but i want to use jquery to modify the header to move it to the top of the page in a transition when the user clicks a link, in addition i want the content to fade once the header has risen. So altering the panels by changing `display: hidden;` 
If someone could offer a solution it would be greatly appreciated [im fairly new to js and havent done jquery before but it seems like jquery is the best library to use]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chris Calcroft &#149; Arbitrator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/stuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='header'>
        <img src='img/header.jpg' alt='header'>
        <ul class='headerNav'>
            <li id='about' onclick='pageChange(id);'>about</li>
            <li id='projects' onclick='pageChange(id);'>projects</li>
            <li id='contact' onclick='pageChange(id);'>contact</li>
        </ul>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function pageChanger(id) {  
    $("id").click(function() {  
        $(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");  
    });  
});
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: avant;
    src: url('font/avant.ttf');
}

html {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: avant;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -175px;
    margin-left: -450px;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s ease, 
                left 2s ease, 
                margin-left 2s ease, 
                margin-top 2s ease,
                position 2s ease;
}

.header-transition {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: static;
    display: block;
}

li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: .2% 1.3%;
}

li:hover {
    color: gray;
}
```

This is what I have so far. I hit a wall when trying to pass the correct id to the jquery for it to toggle the class.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: In jsFiddle i can't see anything without a black background!!!! Do you just want to toggle the css class on every li click event?

Comment: yeh also have hidden text sections which appear on clicking the relevant button

Answer (score 0):

$("id") means all elements that their tag names are **id**

you must use id in the function as below but however I don't think this is what you want.

```
$(function pageChanger(id) {  
    $("#"+id).click(function() {  
        $(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");  
    });  
});
```

if I have understood your case you should do:

```
$('.headerNav li').click(function(){
$(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");  
});
```

for more about selectors visit [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Edit:

If each li will do something different then you should either give them ids and do:

```
$('#about').click( function(){
......
});
$('#project').click( function(){
......
});
$('#contact').click( function(){
......
});
```

and do this for all others. or:

```
 $('.headerNav li').click(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'about':
               //do something
        case 'project':
               //do something else
        case 'contact':
               //do another thing
        }
    });
```

Comment: great answer thanks, when i do `$('.headerNav li').click(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'about':
               $(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");
        case 'project':
               $(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");
        case 'contact':
               $(".header").toggleClass(".header-transition");
        }
    });` it doesn't change

Comment: It won't change as the toggleClass only takes the value of the class name excluding the period character(.) . So remove the period character (.) . It'll work then.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong at first glance:

- You are binding your click event twice - both via inline HTML onclick handler, and via jQuery click() method in your script.
- The function you are binding in your onclick events has a different name to the one you're defining in your script, so nothing will be called when the event fires.
- You're defining a named function inside your closure e.g. $(function pageChanger(id)...
  This doesn't look right to me but I might be wrong on this.
- The way you're passing your id to the function on each click event is wrong.
  In your onclick statements you're passing 'id' to the function, which I assume you mean to be the value of the element's ID attribute, but this will not work.
  On the other hand, in your script, you define your function's parameter as 'id', but then refer to it inside the function as a string in quotes i.e. "id".  Because of this, your jQuery selector object $("id").click, in this form, is telling jQuery to select an 'id' element, which is invalid (there is no 'id' element in HTML).

Maybe a little off-topic here but I hope the above can help to improve your general knowledge of JS / jQuery.

What you can do is stick with the click() method in your script but, rather than use it in a function, you can simply bind it to your list elements directly.
Note: you might be better to put anchor elements  inside your list elements and attach the click event to those as this is semantically better markup, and should avoid failed event firing in legacy browsers (I think IE7 doesn't listen to click events that aren't bound to anchor elements).

Try the following:

```
Change links to -
<li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>

Change JS to this -
$(function(){
  $(".headerNav a").click(function(e){
     var elem = $(e.target), // e.target points to the element that triggered the event
         elemId = elem.attr("id");

     // it isn't clear what each unique element's click event will do, but here is where you defien that logic      
  })
})

Using e.target in a jQuery object is a much cleaner and more efficient way to dynamically bind an event to multiple elements.
```

I hope you find some / any of this useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will toggle the header css on every list item click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentCssClass = $(".header").attr("class");
    $(".header > ul > li").click(function(){
        $(".header").toggleClass("header-transition");
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/USYAs/)

Comment: hi thats got it moving great :) thanks could you be a star and see in my css what i need to change to make it simply slide up the page to the top, as currently it hops over the the top left? thank you :)

Comment: which element you want to slide up?? you can certainly do that transition using jQuery.

Comment: I've got it to move in the correct way and also show text based on the link that is clicked but if youre on about for example and click projects the text doesnt change you have to turn off the visibility for about using the button then open the projects panel. in addition every time i click it it always moves up and down i want it to stay at the top once clicked. here is the jquery:

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header > ul > li").click(function(){
         $(".header").toggleClass("header-transition");
    });
});  

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.headerNav > li').click(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'aboutNav':
             $(".content-hidden-about").toggleClass("content");
        case 'projectsNav':
             $(".content-hidden-project").toggleClass("content");
        case 'contactNav':
             $(".content-hidden-contact").toggleClass("content");
        }
    });
});`

Comment: sorry, but the words are really confusing.I don't see any button. Neither i get which element you want to move or which one you want to let in fixed position.